# See HLS viewer number in Nginx + RTMP module

Tags: nginx, rtmp

I am trying to fetch the actual number of HLS viewers in an Nginx with the [RTMP module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module).

I have tried [this](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Getting-number-of-subscribers) solution but it is not giving me the real number, I think maybe because it's not counting the viewers who are pulling the stream in HLS format.

Is there any 'good' way to achieve that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way by counting the number of IPs that requested HLS/DASH fragments in the last 10 to 20 minutes:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

date_prefix=$(date +'%d/%b/%Y:%H')
cur_min=$(date +'%M')
cur_min_decimal=${cur_min:0:1}
if [[ $cur_min_decimal == '0' ]]
then
    prev_min_decimal=5
else
    prev_min_decimal=$(($cur_min_decimal - 1))
fi
cur_minuted_date="${date_prefix}:${cur_min_decimal}"
prev_minuted_date="${date_prefix}:${prev_min_decimal}"

tail -n 10000 /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    | grep -E 'GET /(hls|dash)/key-' \
    | grep -E "${cur_minuted_date}|${prev_minuted_date}" \
    | awk '{print $1}' \
    | sort \
    | uniq \
    | wc -l
```

If you want to show it on the website, you can CRON that script every minute and output it in the `/var/www/html` folder